# SVG: stretching an image

Tags: image, svg

I'm playing around with the SVG tutorial and I simply loaded an image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg style="stroke-linejoin:round; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.5pt; text-anchor:middle; fill:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, FreeSans, Sans, sans, sans-serif" height="400px" width="400px" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
    <rect y="0" x="0" height="250" width="250" stroke="black"  stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
    <image y="0" x="0" height="250" width="250" xlink:href="http://www.blueprintmodel.co.uk/images/DSCF1438.jpg" />
</svg>
```

I get image in the center of viewBox, over "rect", even if height and width are same.
My questions are:

- How do I stretch an image to be size of rect?
- Why "height" in "image" tag doesn't do the job?
- Is there transformation like "stretch" or "resize" that I can use?(i couldn't find them)

Comment: try a transform attribute like transform="scale(2)" on the image

Comment: I've already tried that, but what I need is to stretch it to be 250x250, so, It could work but in that case I need to know format of the picture, for example if the pic is 4:2,  transform="scale(0.5)" will do the thing. Problem is that I need it for any picture.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Set [`preserveAspectRatio="none"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) on the SVG element:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
```

Comment: Note that this might not work for some (and many mobile) browsers. @Aleksandar

Comment: Please note that `preserveAspectRatio` have no effect unless a `viewBox` exists to define the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: The `preserveAspectRatio` can also be applied as an attribute on `<image>` elements rather than globally to the `<svg>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Answer (score 8):

It is also possible scale and change the aspect ratio of an SVG by using pure CSS:

`transform: scale(x, y);`

Comment: Note: I understand this answer doesn't answer the original question directly. I needed to resize an SVG while ignoring the aspect-ratio, which brought me to this Q&A, but I found the CSS approach was more appropriate in my situation, so I'm sharing it here for others that may find it useful.

Comment: This will work for some scenarios but bear in mind that this can cause the SVG to overlap with other elements as transform does not "push" elements around

Answer (score 4):

When working with SVG images, please learn about how `preserveAspectRatio`
works — with it, you can make the SVG images responsive in any way you like!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

To answer your questions:

- How do I stretch an image to be size of rect?

  `<image viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none" … />`
- Why "height" in "image" tag doesn't do the job?

  I don’t know what the problem with the image was because the original image is gone. Anyway, with SVG you should concentrate on using viewBox instead of width and height. You know, the name contains the word ‘scalable’, and using width and height prevents that…
- Is there transformation like "stretch" or "resize" that I can use?

  Centered and contained:
  `<image viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" …`

  Centered and covered:
  `<image viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" …`

PS. Everything you need ever wanted to know about gotchas in scaling SVG images (but please forget about IE already, and do not use the padding-bottom hacks): https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/