# D3js: How to stretch object vertically?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I got a map in lat/long projection which get quite flat given higher latitudes, such :

[image]

To make it look good, I know I can vertically stretch it by 140%, such:

[image]

Also, **how could I strech my SVG element AND its content with D3 ?** (I can't use CSS since the underlying SVG would then not be fine in itself. I need the SVG code to be stretched, allowing download)

Note: for an online code sample, I got [India  at the moment](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/_location_map-en.html) (India just need a stretch of 106% however, but same idea).

Comment: Maybe use [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464101/svg-stretching-an-image) with a fixed height and width that you define before ?

Comment: This didn't work, that expand the frame without expanding the content.

Comment: could it be a projection-related problem? have you tried changing the projection?

Comment: It's indeed a property of the lat/long projection to increasingly flatten objects toward poles. Wikipedia's maps are built upon this equirectangular and associated (and provided) strechs rations to counter the flattening. So I **must reuse** this projection and these stretch to not disturb other systems lower on the workflow (on wikipedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG elements can be scaled by setting a transform attribute. So take the container of your shapes and do

```
container.setAttribute("transform", "scale(1, 1.4)");
```

You need to have a transformable container though e.g. a `<g>` element. An `<svg>` element is not transformable in SVG 1.1 but will be in the upcoming SVG 2 specification. As far as I know only Firefox and Opera support that part of SVG 2 so far.

If you want to make this work on the map of India with an SVG 1.1 UA since you have no transformable container you could either set the transform on every path and text element e.g.

```
<svg>
  <path transform="scale(1, 1.4).../>
  <path transform="scale(1, 1.4).../>
  <text transform="scale(1, 1.4).../>
</svg>
```

You'd have to loop over the children of the `<svg>` element to do that.

Alternatively you could to insert a `<g>` element in the hierarchy i.e.

```
<svg>
  <path .../>
  <path .../>
</svg>
```

would become

```
<svg>
  <g transform="scale(1, 1.4)">
    <path .../>
    <path .../>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You would iterate over all the child elements of the `<svg>` and reparent them to the `<g>` element and then set a transform on the `<g>` element.

Comment: Do you mean something like JQuery `$("svg").setAttribute("transform", "scale(1, 1.4)");`

Comment: Damn. I put all my items in class. No containers out of SVG. But I get a direction.